# Read DPI metadata from a GIF image

Tags: java, metadata, gif, javax.imageio

I have been successful in reading the DPI (PPI, actually) of .png, .jpeg, .tif and .jpf images using the `javax.imageio` lib. I would parse the `javax_imageio_1.0` metadata and look for *VerticalPixelSize* and *HorizontalPixelSize* values using the following code:

```
  public static int getImageVerticalDensity(String imagePath) throws IOException {
    IIOMetadataNode root = initReader(imagePath);
    if (root != null) {
      NodeList nodes = root.getElementsByTagName("VerticalPixelSize");
      if (nodes.getLength() > 0) {
        IIOMetadataNode dpcWidth = (IIOMetadataNode) nodes.item(0);
        NamedNodeMap nnm = dpcWidth.getAttributes();
        Node item = nnm.item(0);
        int xDPI = Math.round(25.4f / Float.parseFloat(item.getNodeValue()));
        return xDPI;
      }
    }
    return 0;
  }

  private static IIOMetadataNode initReader(String imagePath) throws IOException {
    ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new File(imagePath));
    Iterator it = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);
    if (!it.hasNext()) {
      return null;
    }
    ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) it.next();
    reader.setInput(iis);
    IIOMetadata meta = reader.getImageMetadata(0);
    IIOMetadataNode root = (IIOMetadataNode) meta.getAsTree("javax_imageio_1.0");
    return root;
  }
```

Seems like there are no *VerticalPixelSize* and *HorizontalPixelSize* tags in the GIF metadata, defined in the [javadoc](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java7/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/gif_metadata.html). Since I am not that experienced in reading the metadata, is there a way to calculate pixels per inch/mm/whatever from the available values in the .gif metadata?

Comment: I think GIF is a format designed for images to be displayed on screen. In such formats a pixel is just a pixel, its physical size depends on your screen resolution. I don't think it can be computed, or if it even makes sense to try... Just assume some default value, I think traditionally computer screens were thought of as having 72 DPI (even if they didn't), so using this value may make sense.  But you could just as well use 96, 150 or whatever you think work best for your use case. What do you need this DPI setting for?

Comment: @HaraldK I am determining position of the text previously OCRed inside another module, where the base unit is set to a physical unit (mm and inches) and some other calculations are performed on top of it. In other cases, I would extract DPI and convert it to a common unit, but in case of .gif I am not able to do the conversion since there is no common unit other than width/height in pixels.

Comment: In that case, what DPI does the OCR module think the GIF has? As there is no physical size encoded in the GIF, it really doesn't matter what the value is, but it's probably a good idea that the modules agree on the value.